# Text se sale del contenedor

Tags: php, css, bulma

**Hola:**

Tengo el siguiente problema:

- Cuando agrego un insert a la base de datos con el texto de letras repetidas o numeros sin separarlos, estos al mostrarse en mi web se defasan del contenedor.
- Esto no pasa cuando escribo un texto normal separado por espacios por ejemplo: **el niño corria por la calle el dia sabado** pero si pasa cuando escribo algo como **dddddddddddddddddddddddddd111111111**

Les dejo un ejemplo en una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código front

```
                   <div class="box">
                        <div class="menu-label has-text-centered">
                            COMENTARIOS
                        </div>
                        <!-- COMENTARIOS -->
                        <?php foreach ($execute_comentario_post as $comentarios_total => $valor) : ?>
                            <!-- new -->
                            <article class="media">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <figure class="image is-64x64">
                                        <img src="<?= HOST ?>/templates/img/coment.jpeg" alt="Waidoo">
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong>Anonimo</strong>
                                            <br>
                                            <?= $valor[1]; ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </article>
                            <!-- new -->
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <!-- COMENTARIOS -->
                    </div>
```

y este el codigo php

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    $comentario_txt = isset($_POST['comment']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($database, limpiar_datos($_POST['comment'])) : false;
    $errores = [];

    if (iconv_strlen($comentario_txt) >= 10 && iconv_strlen($comentario_txt) <= 255) {
        $comentario_txt_dos_validado = true;
    } else {
        $comentario_txt_dos_validado = false;
        $errores['commentdos'] = "EL COMENTARIO DEBE SER MAYOR A 10 CARACTERES Y MENOR A 255 CARACTERES";
    }

    $guardar_post = false;

    if (count($errores) == 0 || empty($errores)) {
        $guardar_post = true;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comentarios VALUES(null, '$comentario_txt', '$id');";
        $guardar = $database->query($sql);

        if ($guardar) {
            $errores['guardado'] = "COMENTARIO PUBLICADO";
        } else {
            $errores['error_general'] = "OCURRIO UN ERROR AL INTENTAR PUBLICAR";
        }
    } else {
        $errores['errores'] = $errores;
    }
}

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Funcion para limpiar los datos del formulario
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------
function limpiar_datos($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Actualmente me encuentro utilizando **Bulma framework** para diseñar el front-end y **php 7.4  - mysql** para el backend

Comment: Siempre puedes hacer una función de PHP que a la hora de enviar un string a la vista "rompa" las palabras demasiado largas, por ejemplo insertando un espacio, o cortandolas a una longitud dada según el caso... Recientemente hice una búsqueda de "nombres de lugares más largos" para ver que entradas de formulario podían romperme el diseño y donde cortar... Plantee una pregunta relacionada con esta, tal vez opuesta aquí: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128109/evitar-ruptura-de-cadena-de-caracteres-cuando-termina-el-espacio-horizontal-disp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa la propiedad [word-break:break-word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) o [overflow-wrap:break-word;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap) de CSS para cortar palabras que no quepan en una sola línea. Ambas tienen buen soporte de navagadores, pero la primera está marcada como obsoleta.

```css
.comentario {
  width:350px;
  overflow-wrap:break-word;
  border:1px #aaa solid;
  margin:10px;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comentario">
Se va a cortar donde el texto llegue al límite sin cortar palabras que caben dentro de la línea aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
<div class="comentario">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: Que hay acerca del detalle que la doc linkeada la marca como *deprecated*?, Duda real

Comment: @BetaM, edité la respuesta, agregando una opción que no está marcada como obsoleta y funciona exactamente igual.